powershelll profile which only prints in interactive
Why is it so hard to have a powershell profile which does certain things only if it is executed inside an interactive host.
With Linux shells it is quite easy to differentiate between profile and rc scripts so things you want to only exist in an interactive session are only loaded then. I was not able to do the same with powershell (5.1 on Windows 11). Even Google and ChatGPT only suggests things which dont work. I cant use $Args or $Host.Name or Host.UI.RawUI.KeyAvailable or $MyInvocation because the simple condition "when powershell.exe -command or powershell.exe -file is used or "run in powershell" in the explorer, then a certain codeblock in my profile script should be skipped.
I know I can use -NoProfile and it is quite important to use it always. Nevertheless I want my profile.ps1 to be a good citizen and not require this. Not to mention I want to understand why this is so hard and why it is nowhere mentioned as a best practice and why you find only answers which do not work.
For example $Host.Name is 'ConsoleHost' when i start powershell.exe from another powershell.exe which is of course a normal thing if you try to use only powershell windows.
In my case I dont care if it is a session in Windows Terminal, a VS Code Terminal Windows or a old-style powershell.exe host (cause its started with "Run as Admin"), in only those cases I want my profile if code to fire.
I could probably use $PID and poke at the process, but this looks awfully compliacted for a seemingly commonly required task?

Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9738535/powershell-test-for-noninteractive-mode for some examples of this. One problem you have is that running powershell.exe -c foo from cmd would count as interactive for most people. You could still use [Environment]::GetCommandLineArgs() to check for it pretty easily though

@Cpt.Whale Yes indeed, with some guesswork I should be able to recognize "login" shells with that. Please make an answer out of it, will accept it.

You can use [Environment]::GetCommandLineArgs() to check for non-interactive type parameters like -command or -file
